# JWT token being removed while using Anguar2 router

Tags: angular, jwt, router

I am creating an Angular2/ Node.js application with JWT authentication. My authentication works perfect and the JWT token is being stored in local storage.

Now, I am landing into some other html page by clicking a link through router and there is no server call. However in that new page the JWT token is bing removed from local storage. I am not loading the entire page and it stays in the same browser, so not sure why the token is missing from local storage. Any help/ recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Below is my router definition

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path : '', component : LoginComponent},
{path : 'logout', component : LoginComponent},
{path : 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path : 'themes', component: ThemesComponent},
//{path : 'contactUs', component : ReportComponent}
// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

];

Regards

Comment: Please add the code that stores and retrieves the token. Note this has nothing to do with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are adding the value to local storage? Use Chrome dev tools to check and make sure you can see the value under Application. Here's googles doc on using the dev tools to check this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage

I suspect it's not being set because LocalStorage is very persistent, you can close the browser and open it back up and the value will still be there, you need to explicitly delete it to remove it.

One other possibility is your domain is changing and the browser thinks you're on a new site, but since it looks like you're just using the router to navigate to a route in the angular app, which doesn't refresh the page or navigate anywhere (it just pushes a history state) that's unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the devtools link. It helped me found the issue, which was an application issue.